# Beautiful Soup does not get full div

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

BeautifulSoup does something weird and I can't figure out why.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "nsfw"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
cards = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "card-body"})
cards.pop(0)
cards.pop(0)
cards.pop(0)  # i really like to pop
texte = []
print(soup)
for i, card in enumerate(cards):
    texte.append(card.text)
    if i == len(cards)-1:
        print(card)
```

Now what I expect it to do is get the divs and to put the text of the divs into the array. And it does work. For the first 8 out of 9 divs. The 9th div is extremly shortened. Result of the print:

```html
<div class="card-body" id="card_Part_9"><p class="storytext"><span class="brk2_firstwords">“Door’s open,” Brendan shouted.</span></p>
    <p class="storytext">Jeffrey</p></div>
```

But on the website itself it doesn't end there. Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZRgJ.png

Why does this happen? What can I do to prevent this? I have already tried to change the parser, but that does not change the result. The site does not use Javascript to load content.

Structure when opening with a browser: https://pastebin.com/N2bPYFBD

But when I print(soup) I get:

````html
<p class="storytext">Jeffrey</p></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></body></html> entered the apartment```
````

Comment: I would guess that the paragraph below the title is in the next `p` tag with `class="storytext"`

Comment: @OD1995 the whole divs just consists of a lot of p tags. But the first 8 were no problem?

Comment: That is odd. It's difficult to offer help much more without the URL but perhaps you'll have to treat the final div differently to make your code work? Also, a side tip, you can use `for i, card in enumerate(cards):` instead of having to `i=0` and `i = i + 1`

Comment: Is the structure of 9th div exactly the same than the others? Can you at least post the code of the 8th and the 9th ?

Comment: @Maaz I've extracted the code structure (and replaced the text) of the 2 divs: https://pastebin.com/N2bPYFBD As far as I can see it has the exact same strucuture as the other one.

Comment: @OD1995 Thank you for the tip, I didn't know that. I've changed the code sample to that.

Comment: @StackHogger Apologies, didn't realise you wanted `i` to start at 1 rather than 0, you can do `enumerate(cards,1)` to achieve that. Also, your pastebin link isn't working for me, is that definitely the right link?

Comment: It looks like some of the content is loaded dynamically and can't be fetched with with bs. Look at the soup-object. It end's with "Jeffrey". It didn't work with a user-agent neither for me.

Comment: Just checked: it's working with selenium.

Comment: @Gregor I am not sure what you mean. When I print(soup) it has the full page including all the text of the 9th div? I also blocked javascript in my browser and it still shows everything

Comment: @OD1995 The link should work, I think, but here is an alternative: https://hastebin.com/elexisejun.xml

Comment: @StackHogger I printed the soup-object and it did not contain all the text from the story. I suspect that some of the content is loaded dynamically (e.g. via javascript) and BeautifulSoup cannot fetch such kind of data. I tried using selenium, that emulates a browser and can interact with dynamic content, and I was able to fetch the complete story.

Comment: Just found out that when I print(soup) that the document seems to be weird at this part `<p class="storytext">Jeffrey</p></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></body></html> entered the apartment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the `html.parser` messes up the DOM. The `lxml`-parser works for me:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "six-pack-thingy"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
cards = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "card-body"})
texte = [card.text for card in cards[3:]]
```

Comment: I've tried that yesterday... And I could have sworn, that it didn't work... Why does it work now, am I going insane? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Thought I could post my scribble as well:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('six-pack-thingy')
elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('card-body')

texte = [t.text for t in elems[3:]]
```

You will have to get some webdriver to run selenium, though. Are you familiar with that?

Comment: Thank you, this would work as an alternative. Of course this would slow things down quite a bit, so I'll try to find another solution. If I fail at that, I will come back to this, thank you.